# Is $N \otimes_R M$ isomorphic to $N \otimes_R M'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and $N$, $M$ and $M'$ be $R$-algebras. Suppose I know that $M$ and $M'$ are isomorphic as rings. 
Does it then follow that $N \otimes_R M$ is isomorphic to $N \otimes_R M'$?

If not, does it follows if $M$ and $M'$ are isomorphic as $R$-algebras perhaps?
Thank you

Comment: If they are isomorphic as $R$-algebras, then it follows from functoriality of $N\otimes_R -$

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Could you possibly explain me what does `functoriality' mean?

Comment: It means that given an $R$-linear map $K\to K'$ you get a linear map $N\otimes_R K\to N\otimes_R K'$ and that these "induced maps" compose nicely : $N\otimes_R (f\circ g) = (N\otimes_R f)\circ (N\otimes_R g) $ and $N\otimes_R id_K = id_{N\otimes_R K}$

Comment: @WoolierThanThou shouldn't this be true without the $R$-algebra assumption by the fact that $N\otimes_R-$ is a functor, since functors preserve isomorphisms?

Comment: The tensor product over $R$ isn't a functor out of the category of rings, so there's no reason it should do anything to maps which are just ring homomorphisms, even when we can give meaning to the tensor product. You could reduce to the case where $M$ and $M'$ are only assumed to be $R$-modules, but the isomorphism you get need not be an algebra homomorphism.

Comment: Ah, right, if the ring isomorphism is not a map of $R$-modules then $N\otimes_R-$ doesn't act on it. Thanks for the reminder.